# The map $p(x)\mapsto p(x+1)$ in vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I encountered this question in a previous year paper of an exam. I wish somebody could help me how to go by this question.

Choose the correct option

Let $N$ be the vector space of all real polynomials of degree at most $3$. Define
$$S:N \to N \ \text{by} \ (Sp)(x)=p(x+1), \ p \in N$$
Then the matrix of $S$ in the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, considered as column vectors, is given by

1. \begin{bmatrix}1 &0 &0& 0\\
     0& 2& 0& 0\\
   0 &0& 3& 0\\
   0& 0& 0& 4\end{bmatrix}
2. \begin{bmatrix}1& 1& 1& 1\\
   0& 1 &2 &3\\
   0 &0& 1& 3\\
   0& 0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}
3. \begin{bmatrix}1& 1& 2& 3\\
   1 &1 &2& 3\\
   2 &2 &2 &3\\
   3 &3& 3 &3\end{bmatrix}
4. \begin{bmatrix} 0& 0& 0& 0\\
   1& 0 &0 &0\\
   0& 1& 0& 0\\
   0 &0 &1& 0\end{bmatrix}

How to tackle p(x+1) thing?

Comment: You can check what $S$ does to the basis elements, and you can check what those matrices do to basis elements.  One of the matrices does the same thing $S$ does.  Are you having trouble doing this checking?

Comment: yes @JonasMeyer, i am having a great trouble. I last studied Maths 2 years back. Now, i've to take some exam and m not able to do even basic questions. I really hope u could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you can begin computing the images of $1, x, x^2$ and $x^3$. For instance:

$$
S(1) = 1 \ ,
$$

because it doesn't matter wherever you evaluate the constant polynomial $1$, its value will always be $1$. Next, you compute also

$$
S(x) = x + 1 \ , \qquad S(x^2) = (x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 
$$

and

$$
\qquad S(x^3) = (x+1)^3 = \dots
$$

Then, you think about the coordinates of these polynomials in the basis $1, x, x^2, x^3$. For instance,

$$
1 = 1\cdot 1 + 0\cdot x +0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 \ .
$$

So the coordinates of $S(1) = 1$ are

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0  \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This way you've obtained the first column of your matrix. The second column will be the coordinates of $S(x) = x + 1$. That is,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1  \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The third one, those of $S(x^2)$,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2  \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And the last one?

Comment: It is multiple choice, so we could stop with the second column. :)

Comment: Yep. There should be a last choice in order to avoid lazy people do their work: "(5) None of the above."   :-)

Comment: yes, i was a fool to have said otherwise.

Comment: You fooled me too, don't worry.  :-)